# UILabel getting clipped on 3.5" iPhone 4 screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

Can someone help me figure this out: I have done some research around here but nothing seems to work. I have tried working with the size inspector, I have also tried adding the following to my view with no success

`[view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];`

I would really appreciate some help here, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by using autolayout like shown below.

[image]

Have a look at this tutorial on how to use it: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/

Comment: Can you please explain how I can use the auto layout feature & add the constraints? The Autolayout is checked ON in the inspector for the view already  @daniellarsson

Answer (score 1):

Use auto layout and constraints. You need to click on UILabel and press "Control" button and drag the cursor downwards and then select the bottom space constraint. Like wise you need to set all the constraints for X, Y , Height and Width of the UILabel and you should be good to see the label at the same place on all kinds of devices.